# Automatic Allow Privacy of the Electron App

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I have an Electron APP that counts all mouse click and keyboard press. The App still run but the count function is not working because the the privacy's locked.Is there a method can electron app automatic allow Accessibility->Privacy on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

The app should request permissions the first time it is run on a new computer and tries to access something that is restricted. This is automatic and shouldn't require you to code anything specific to get it to work.

If the app isn't signed though, it will require new permissions every time it changes (updates count). Often in development, you will update the .app file with new features and so it will 'lose' it's permissions and won't request them. You will have to manually go into the system preferences and disable then enable the accessibility settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use tccutil reset All to reset permissions be aware that All reset other apps granted permissions as well